# node js multi part file upload to django not showing my file in request.FILES.get('filename')

Tags: node.js, django, http, post, django-views

I'm using the [requests npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library for node js and attempting to do a multipart upload to an api.

How can I set up my body of my post request to be properly be recognized by

```
[request.FILES.get('filename')][1]
```

In the django framework?

I'm currently formatting my post request as shown below.

```
body = {file_size: bytes ,checksum_sha256: sha256, checksum_md5: md5, part: i}
```

I'm really not sure how to tie declaring the image a file so the django framework recognizes it, naming it, and actually linking the data together with

```
fs.createReadStream(filepath);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use form with multipart to send Files, django receive files and post it as `request.FILES` as you know.

If you upload file with like this:

`<input type="file" name="aaa" />`

then you can your file with `request.FILES['aaa']`, not your filename.

and if you want to know uploaded file's name, you can handle like this:

`request.FILES['aaa'].name`

Check this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES